# VBA Internet Explorer: Not able to fill a WebForm

Tags: ms-access, internet-explorer, vba

I have the following code to fill a webform, but in this particular website the code is not working:

```
Const loginSelectSistema_Name = "url"
Const loginInputUsuário_Name = "Usuario"
Const loginInputSenha_Name = "Senha"
Const loginInputOk_Name = "imageField2"

Const USERNAME = "NomeUsuário"
Const PASSWORD = "SenhaAcesso"

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim iePage As HTMLDocument

Function loginPage()
    '
    Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer
    '
    ieApp.Visible = True
    ieApp.navigate (loginWebsite)
    '
    'Wait for page to load
    Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
    '
    '
    Set iePage = ieApp.Document
    '
    fillInputObject loginSelectSistema_Name, "jcaa"
    fillInputObject loginInputUsuário_Name, USERNAME
    fillInputObject loginInputSenha_Name, PASSWORD
    '
    iePage.all.Item(loginInputOk_Name).Click
End Function

Private Sub fillInputObject(ByVal objectName As String, ByVal value As String, Optional IdentificadorElemento As IdentificadorElementoHTML = Nome)
'
'Preenche o Objeto Input com um determinado valor
    Dim elementHTML As HTMLObjectElement
    '
    If (IdentificadorElemento = Nome) Then
        Set elementHTML = iePage.getElementsByName(objectName).Item
    End If
    '
    If (IdentificadorElemento = Id) Then
        Set elementHTML = iePage.getElementById(objectName)
    End If
    '
    If (IsObject(elementHTML)) Then
        If (Not (elementHTML Is Nothing)) Then
            elementHTML.value = value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

When debugging, in Function `fillInputObject` the line: `If (Not (elementHTML Is Nothing)) Then` the value is always *Nothing*, and the webform is not filled.

Below is the page in HTML that I trying to fill the webform:

```
<table width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bordercolor="#DADADA" border="1" bgcolor="#F7F7F8" align="center" height="110">
    <tbody><tr height="2"><td width="62"></td><td width="0"></td><td width="592"></td><td width="223"></td></tr>
          <tr height="15">
             <td colspan="4" bordercolor="#F7F7F8" style="vertical-align:left"><strong>Selecione o Sistema:</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr height="15">
             <td colspan="4" bordercolor="#F7F7F8" style="vertical-align:left">
                <font size="1px" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
               <select name="url" class="combobox" style="width:180px;">

                 <option value="jcaa">Cadastro de Alunos</option>
                 <option value="paef">Cadastro Funcional</option>
                 <option value="paec">Controle de Freqüência</option>
                 <option value="papc">Desp de Pessoal (SDPE)</option>

                 <option value="jcgo">Cargos</option>
                 <option value="paea">Contagem de Tempo</option>
                 <option value="jata">Formação Curricular</option>
                 <option value="jrha">Gratificação / Promoção QM</option>
                 <option value="paex">PAEX - Cadastro Funcional</option>
               </select>
             </font>
             </td>
          </tr>
            <tr height="2"><td colspan="4" bordercolor="#F7F7F8"></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" bordercolor="#F7F7F8" align="left">
                    <font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                        Usuário
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" bordercolor="#F7F7F8" align="left">
                    <input id="Usuario" name="Usuario" size="10" maxlength="10" value="SE0452336A" type="text">
                </td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" bordercolor="#F7F7F8" align="left">
                    <font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
                    Senha
                    </font>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" bordercolor="#F7F7F8" align="left">
                    <input id="Senha" name="Senha" size="14" maxlength="14" type="password">
                </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" bordercolor="#F7F7F8" align="left">
                    <font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">&nbsp;

                    </font>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" bordercolor="#F7F7F8" align="left">
                    <input name="imageField2" src="images/ok_sen.gif" width="24" type="image" border="0" height="17">
                </td></tr>

        </tbody></table>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is in the `Nome` and how the `IdentificadorElementoHTML ` is implemented?

Comment: @dee IdentificadorElementoHTML is an Enum that holds some elements, among them Nome (representing an Integer. The purpose is to add more flexibility in code. If the value is Nome, the element is gotten by its name, if the value is Id, the element is gotten by its Id, and so on... It only depends the webpage element identifier...

Comment: I see, so when I test your code with the given HTML it works fine for `Usuario` and for `Senha` names. What value is in `loginInputUsuário_Name` and in `loginInputSenha_Name`?

Comment: @dee I just edited the code with the constants used in functions. `loginInputUsuário_Name` stands for the Name of element `Usuario` and `loginInputSenha_Name` represents the name of html element `Senha`

Comment: Well yes, that works. So the code works, the problem could be, that the HTML content you expect to be there is not there when you try to find the input elements. Are you sure, the URL is correct? Are you sure the page is fully loaded? Do you see the page with the inputs on the screen after the code after `'Wait for page to load` has finished?

Comment: @dee I put a breakpoint for debug on `Set iePage = ieApp.Document`, the page was fully loaded on IE and typing F12 in IE, the elements are in the code showed by the browser. The URL is "https://gdaenet.edunet.sp.gov.br/index.html" . Is this problem caused because this is a https website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL provided in the last comment shows the problem. The login form is placed inside of an `IFrame` therefore the current document doesn't know about the elements because they are not there.

You should slightly modify your code so the document of the `IFrame` is used for search.

```
Set iePage = ieApp.document

Dim fr As HTMLIFrame
Set fr = iePage.frames("aplicativos")

Dim iframeDoc As HTMLDocument
Set iframeDoc = iePage.frames("aplicativos").document

fillInputObject iframeDoc, loginSelectSistema_Name, "jcaa"
fillInputObject iframeDoc, loginInputUsuário_Name, USERNAME
fillInputObject iframeDoc, loginInputSenha_Name, PASSWORD

iframeDoc.all.Item(loginInputOk_Name).Click
```

And modify the function `fillInputObject` so it uses the right `Document` object.

```
Private Sub fillInputObject(doc As HTMLDocument, ByVal objectName As String, ByVal Value As String, Optional IdentificadorElemento As IdentificadorElementoHTML = Nome)
'
'Preenche o Objeto Input com um determinado valor
    Dim elementHTML As HTMLObjectElement
    '
    If (IdentificadorElemento = Nome) Then
        Set elementHTML = doc.getElementsByName(objectName).Item
    End If
    '
    If (IdentificadorElemento = ID) Then
        Set elementHTML = doc.getElementById(objectName)
    End If
    '
    If (IsObject(elementHTML)) Then
        If (Not (elementHTML Is Nothing)) Then
            elementHTML.Value = Value
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Man, you're great! I didn't realize there was a frame in that! Thank you!